# php-Mysql multipe search columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm tired to find solution about this subject :(

I'm working on multiple search by using multiple keywords and other clause

My table in BDD in storage MYISAM and collation utf8

```
ad { id,type,title,description,categorie,sub_cat,departement.... }


 $query="SELECT * FROM AD WHERE";

  $keywords=explode(",",$key);

 foreach ($query as $value) {

        $value=trim($value);
        $query.=" (title REGEXP '".$value."' OR description REGEXP '".$value."') OR";
        }
 $query=rtrim($qur,"OR");
 $query.="AND";
 if(!empty($categorie))$query=" (categorie LIKE '".$categorie."') AND";
 foreach ($sub_cat as $value) {
        $query.=" (sub_cat REGEXP '".$value."') OR";
    }
  $query=rtrim($qur,"OR");
  $query.="AND";

   foreach ($departementS as $value) {
        $valuedepartement=(int)$valuedepartement;
        $query.=" (departementAnn=".$valuedepartement." ) OR";

    }
   $query=rtrim($qur,"OR");
   $query.="AND";

   query results:
   $query="SELECT * FROM ad WHERE (title REGEXP 'key1') OR (description REGEXP 'key1')OR (title REGEXP 'key2') OR (description REGEXP 'key2') AND (categorie LIKE 'exmple1') AND (sub_cat=12 OR sub_cat=17).....";
```

I don't have any errors but  the query returns false results

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: @Azrael no that was just a initialization of the first part of the query string, as the logic goes along, it will get appended so finally it will be a complete query, if the logic goes well

Comment: @Ghost I see, xD sorry

Comment: @Azrael no apologies needed :) just clarification. anyways, why not like `description REGEXP 'key1|key2', etc..`

Comment: No that's allright I guess, I just didn't read the `$query .=` parts :P

Comment: but it return a false results @Azrael

Comment: `$categorie = "%'; DELETE FROM AD; --";` Just sayin'. You may want to read more about SQL Injection and prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues.

First, you're going through `$query` as if it's an array. I think you're intending to iterate `$keywords`?

You're referencing `$qur` in multiple locations (should be `$query` presumably)

If searching by category you're resetting query instead of appending to it. (`$query=...` instead of `$query.=...`)

Other than the last thing there these could be easily discovered by using error reporting which is a good idea during development:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You should wrap each section of ORs in parenthesis to properly separate them. This necessitates checking for empty so you don't end up with `AND () AND ...`

You're adding an extra AND at the end with nothing else. That should be changed to rtrim "ANDWHER" so the final AND is removed and if there is no criteria the WHERE is also removed.

`$valuedepartement=(int)$valuedepartement` should be `$valuedepartement=(int)$value;`. When this is called, `$valuedepartement` isn't yet defined.

So the final code would be:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM AD WHERE";

$keywords=explode(",",$key);

if (!empty($keywords)) {
        $query .= ' (';
        foreach ($keywords as $value) {

                $value=trim($value);
                $query.=" (title REGEXP '".$value."' OR description REGEXP '".$value."') OR";
        }
        $query=rtrim($query,"OR") . ') AND ';
}
if(!empty($categorie))$query.=" (categorie LIKE '".$categorie."') AND ";
if (!empty($sub_cat)) {
        $query .= '(';
        foreach ($sub_cat as $value) {
                $query.=" (sub_cat REGEXP '".$value."') OR";
        }
        $query=rtrim($query,"OR") . ') AND ';
}
if (!empty($departementS)) {
        $query .= '(';
        foreach ($departementS as $value) {
                $valuedepartement=(int)$value;
                $query.=" (departementAnn=".$valuedepartement." ) OR";

        }
        $query=rtrim($query,"OR") . ')';
}
$query = rtrim($query, 'ANDWHER ');
echo $query;
```

This generates the query which I believe is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM AD WHERE ( (title REGEXP 'key1' OR description REGEXP 'key1') OR (title REGEXP 'key2' OR description REGEXP 'key2') ) AND  (categorie LIKE 'exmple1') AND ( (sub_cat REGEXP '12') OR (sub_cat REGEXP '17') )
```

I used the following input data for that:

```
$key = 'key1,key2';
$categorie = 'exmple1';
$sub_cat=array(12, 17);
$departementS = array();
```

Cheers